# value = self.cache[key] Key error while working with Python shelve

Tags: python, keyerror, shelve

Here's the code:

```
#! python3
# Locker
'''Usage: Window + R: locker <site>
                      locker update <site> <password>
                      locker delete <site>
                      locker all '''

import sys,shelve,pyperclip
getPass = shelve.open('puppy')
if sys.argv[1] != 'all':
    pyperclip.copy(getPass[sys.argv[1]])
    print('Password of',sys.argv[1],'copied to clipboard.')
elif sys.argv[1] == 'update':
    getPass[sys.argv[2]]=sys.argv[3]
    print('Update password for',sys.argv[2],'in database.')
elif sys.argv[1] == 'delete':
    del getPass[sys.argv[2]]
    print('Password for',sys.argv[2],'removed from database.')
elif sys.argv[1] == 'all':
    print('Current Database:'.center(30))
    for site,key in list(getPass.items()):
        print(str(site).ljust(20,'.'),end='')
        print(key.ljust(20))

getPass.close()
```

1/What it does? well, you can pretty much tell. I made a small program to save my passwords. Whenever I want to get my password for some site quickly I just need to open Run and type "locker (site)" and the password will be copied to the clipboard and I just simply paste it in the password field. Other tasks such as updating passwords or deleting password are added as well and you can see their syntax in the code. ( I did create a .bat file to make running this program easier)
2/The problem? it throws a KeyError when I try to use the update or delete syntax and I can't figure out why:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pminh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\shelve.py", line 111, in __getitem__
    value = self.cache[key]
KeyError: 'update'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pminh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\locker.py", line 12, in <module>
    pyperclip.copy(getPass[sys.argv[1]])
  File "C:\Users\pminh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\shelve.py", line 113, in __getitem__
    f = BytesIO(self.dict[key.encode(self.keyencoding)])
  File "C:\Users\pminh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\dbm\dumb.py", line 153, in __getitem__
    pos, siz = self._index[key]     # may raise KeyError
KeyError: b'update'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: The comment told you it may raise KeyError

Comment: Your second and third conditionals are unreachable: an input of 'update' or 'delete' matches the first conditional (`!= 'all'`), and gets interpreted as a site to look up.